# How do I verify an Auth0 JWT signature in terminal with OpenSSL using a public key?

Tags: bash, openssl, jwt, auth0

I am trying to manually verify the signature in a JWT using OpenSSL. From [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijg1c1ZGNW5Vdl9CS2tiWF9pTUVzTSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NvYmVyLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJWTlFFdjZqeFg1Tzl6T0o5ZzJqVW9JN2NzczdxcFg2MEBjbGllbnRzIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zb2JlcmFwaS5zb2xzdGFkLmRldi8iLCJpYXQiOjE1OTk2Mjk3ODMsImV4cCI6MTU5OTcxNjE4MywiYXpwIjoiVk5RRXY2anhYNU85ek9KOWcyalVvSTdjc3M3cXBYNjAiLCJndHkiOiJjbGllbnQtY3JlZGVudGlhbHMifQ.XlY8ClqS5TAQPELgnaWIhKqHif7v1DwyL0rSUeFVllx6NMLX7GhuYd6cH_4Qkxj10Sfm2qPIF4J9BEFUuJWrb_NfUuTVuodA41p-I6mnES1N3-4T-tC-ZEPhCEzE1R66M5c00SoRBbPLGUU--m87HpL-CcDE51FcrfXRjQR2o8qJsc0Pb_baRcGXQ6EquM3TW5ZX4XlJ7ErsWPv09Upo1ZO0sdP4c2SS3Agz_H05nOy7ZQh5JTBu9RpRqAs05VuREz1BbiuqDneUkn6rJrBcqHWJI1RrDY7fmYNBWX-c85_hEijnvfL7eg-UMb7A2uMp0_ZiEQSrpHusgkMyW4ZMEQ&publicKey=-----BEGIN%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0AMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo20nae36OLb2itnd6tUy%0AotU2%2FtfAhKhZqatn4CiOyymRFxWktad4xzu65Kuwv0ggxUqyciLMlR0PTgDItas%2F%0Azdxjg8FhUkoepcq69l0GR3OtRBYBIGq%2BZ0c9TRp%2FDSw7YAN8TIcqlI90MTGljTHk%0AcRJpLlS6kdh7wlGFmeFXcRUqBbkzvsoHxfJspD25X7DCey02CczJ8hfIjnlKCdH4%0AxTvkL3KlWDxwI1xQc9nCq2TrsBe%2F4l428VY8FXRi0%2BuPgM7SKQepBeUw37G%2FOndK%0AnBmPxyQ452G62ML3ZkSvEN0hQ4q6d%2FRxHHsdwcti6xayE0SPoHEzECzekGm9Q0k%2B%0AsQIDAQAB%0A-----END%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0A) I know that the public key verifies the signature, but I am not able to reproduce the result using OpenSSL in terminal. What am I missing?

```sh
$ cat token.b64url 
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ijg1c1ZGNW5Vdl9CS2tiWF9pTUVzTSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NvYmVyLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJWTlFFdjZqeFg1Tzl6T0o5ZzJqVW9JN2NzczdxcFg2MEBjbGllbnRzIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zb2JlcmFwaS5zb2xzdGFkLmRldi8iLCJpYXQiOjE1OTk2Mjk3ODMsImV4cCI6MTU5OTcxNjE4MywiYXpwIjoiVk5RRXY2anhYNU85ek9KOWcyalVvSTdjc3M3cXBYNjAiLCJndHkiOiJjbGllbnQtY3JlZGVudGlhbHMifQ.XlY8ClqS5TAQPELgnaWIhKqHif7v1DwyL0rSUeFVllx6NMLX7GhuYd6cH_4Qkxj10Sfm2qPIF4J9BEFUuJWrb_NfUuTVuodA41p-I6mnES1N3-4T-tC-ZEPhCEzE1R66M5c00SoRBbPLGUU--m87HpL-CcDE51FcrfXRjQR2o8qJsc0Pb_baRcGXQ6EquM3TW5ZX4XlJ7ErsWPv09Upo1ZO0sdP4c2SS3Agz_H05nOy7ZQh5JTBu9RpRqAs05VuREz1BbiuqDneUkn6rJrBcqHWJI1RrDY7fmYNBWX-c85_hEijnvfL7eg-UMb7A2uMp0_ZiEQSrpHusgkMyW4ZMEQ

# Convert to Base64
$ TOKEN_B64=$(cat token.b64url | tr '-' '+' | tr '/' '_')

# Separate signature from token 
$ SIG_B64=$(echo $TOKEN_B64 | cut -d. -f3)

# Base64 decode the signature
$ echo $SIG_B64 | base64 -d > "sig.dat"

# separate body from JWT
$ DAT_B64=$(echo $TOKEN_B64 | cut -d. -f1-2)

# verify signature. (I would expect this call to return "Verification OK")
$ echo $DAT_B64 | openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public_key.pem -signature "sig.dat"
Verification Failure
```

Comment: the signature is a hash from the base64url encoded `header.payload`. Why do you change it to base64? And then your conversion itself is also wrong, it should be `tr '_' '/'`.  In this case it might not hurt, as the header and payload don't contain these characters, but that's just luck.

Comment: don't forget that `echo` adds a newline at the end, so prefer `printf %s "$varname"`, also unquoted variable expansions like `$varname` will perform word splitting and globbing. Side-effects of unquoted variable and extraneous newline may corrupt key verification data.

Comment: Fixing the translation did not work. Neither did replacing 'echo' with 'printf'. One thing that I find strange is that the decoded signature is one byte shorter compared to when I use locally created keyset. Could this be related?